# get parameter map from inputstream

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, inputstream

I am writing my own implementaion of HttpServletRequest. I basicaaly need a copy of `HttpServletrequest`  which is serializable.

I am using tomcat 6.0.35. It has servlet-api version 2.5.

My implementation will have a constructor which will get the `HttpServletRequest` object created by the container.
I have to override the method `getParameterMap()`. In case it is a `GET` request, calling `getParameterMap()` is not a problem. But in case of `POST` request, if i call that method on the `HttpServletRequest`object, i cannot readfrom the `inputstream` of the `HttpServletRequest`object. Hence, i need to override the method to read the `inputstream` and create a `parameterMap` from it and also keep the stream open for reading the remaining data on it.
I know that implementation is container specific.
 I have seen apache-tomcat's implementation of creating `parameterMap` but it is very confusing and complicated. Is there an easier way? or any other implementation that i can use?
Thanks